# How to find text using jquery whilst omitting links

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a piece of functionality that relaces text with links which I want to do using javascript.

Here's some sample html i'll be referencing:

```
<div class="linkify">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <a href="http://...">Nullam elit</a> risus, blandit eu pretium quis, porta a odio. Nullam rhoncus, lectus ac faucibus rutrum, dui massa dignissim nisi, ut auctor ipsum mi eget justo. Nam nec leo eget neque viverra pulvinar a aliquet lorem. Suspendisse sodales odio pretium lacinia pharetra. Donec at sapien a eros fermentum vehicula at sagittis felis. Proin eu venenatis leo. Phasellus volutpat auctor leo, ac dignissim risus fringilla eget.</p>
</div>
```

I want to find a named piece of text within any "linkify" class and wrap it with an `<a>` tag, however I also want to avoid doing this where the parent tag is already an `<a>`.

I'm not too great with jquery and it's a pretty specific requirement to find an answer on Google, but does anyone know how to create this jquery statement?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
$('.linkify').each(function(k, v){

    var text = $(v).find('p').text();

    if(text.indexOf('pieceoftext') > -1){

         var $p = $(v).find('p'),
             newHtml = $p.html()
                        .replace('pieceoftext', '<a href="#">pieceoftext</a>');

         if(!$(v).parent().is('a')){
             $p.html(newHtml);
         }
    }
});
```

The `indexOf` is a bit excessive. I just added it for readability.

http://jsfiddle.net/xvwMc/4/

Comment: This works for normal text within class but the second part should not apply a link if the parent is an embedded link already <div class="linkify"><p>this text is ok to be linked <a href="http://">this text should not be linked</a></p></div>

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function replaceToLink(str,href) {
    $('.linkify :contains("' + str + '")').html(function () {
        var check = $('.linkify a:contains("'+str+'")');
        if(check.length ==0){           
        return $(this).html().replace(str, "<a href='"+href+"'>" + str + "</a>")
        }
    });
}
```

Use it like this

`replaceToLink('nisi','http://google.se');`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/q7W7v/)

Answer (score 0):

This solution will work for an arbitrary set of strings:

```
var matches = ['Nullam elit', 'pretium quis', 'venenatis leo'];

$('.linkify').each(function(idx, el) {
    $.each(matches, function(idx, val) {
        if ($(el).html().indexOf(val) !== -1) {
               $(el).html($(el).html().replace(val, '<a href="#whatever">' + val + '</a>'));
        }
    });
});

$('a a').unwrap(); 
$('a:empty').remove();
```

jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/CTzNU/